# Setting Highlight on Facebook post using RestFB

Tags: facebook, restfb

Using `RestFB` API, how do you set `"highlight"` on a post i.e make a post an highlight so it is obvious and noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this currently, it is not supported within the API.

If it's not here (developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) it's not supported.

Comment: @BabajidePrince No orange mark in this pic http://i.stack.imgur.com/vWogp.png means I didn't down-vote it, so your name calling isn't really acceptable or wanted. If it's not here (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) it's not supported.